# How can I sort urls in bash shell such as hostnames are evaluated before subdomain names?

Tags: bash, sorting, url

I am given a file (usually the content of a grep) that contains one URL per line.

I am looking for a way to sort the urls such as :

1. Sort by Hostname
2. Sort by Subdomain name
3. Sort by Path

Here is an example of a file containing the what there is to sort :

> www.example.com
>
> www.my-website.com
>
> www.example.org
>
> my-website.com
>
> www.my-website.org

And how it would be sorted :

> www.example.com
>
> www.example.org
>
> my-website.com
>
> www.my-website.com
>
> www.my-website.org

For now, I use a solution that's quite suboptimal because I sort by top-level-domain first with

```
... | rev | sort -u | rev
# notice the -u flag in the sort, it is optional but appreciated
```

It should be said that this piece of software is to be used in (forseeably) two cases :

- When analysing the content of Httpd conf files (especially grep-ing ServerName-s and ServerAlias-es and feeding that to DNS-querying operations)
- When analysing the result of some web-crawling ( mostly a recursive `wget` fed to a Flex scanner, to extract URLs)

In both case, most of the URLs are related to each other.

How can I "smart"-sort these URLs in bash ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a dot before www-less hostnames with sed:

```
$ cat dom.txt |sed -e 's/^\([^.]*\.[^.]*\)$/.\1/'|sort -t . -k2|sed -e 's/^\.//'
www.example.com
www.example.org
my-website.com
www.my-website.com
www.my-website.org
```

Comment: would that work with bigger subdomains ? ( my.sub.domain.com for instance )

Comment: Works perfectly, I tested it with my.sub.domain.com long subdomains.